# ActiveAdmin customize view for has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, activeadmin

I'm working on a ActiveAdmin app with this models :

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # A User has many roles for interact on a project
    has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :projects, :through => :role
end
```

**Role**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :project
end
```

**Project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    # A project has many roles for interact
    has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :role
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end
```

To add users with a role on each project I make this form :

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do # Project's fields
        f.input :title
        f.input :code
    end

    f.has_many :roles do |app_f|
        app_f.inputs do
            if !app_f.object.nil?
                app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
            end

            app_f.input :user 
            app_f.input :senior_author
        end
    end
    f.buttons
end
```

My first question is how can I make a  with user.firstname + user.lastname. Actually I have something like this :

```
#<User:0x007fb98a7d6568>
```

Second question is my Role model is a list of boolean attributes :

```
:senior_author
:first_author
:viewer
....
```

Can I make a  with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to just define `to_s` in the model:

```
def to_s 
  "#{email} | #{firstname} #{lastname}" 
end
```

No need to set :label_method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `:label_method => lambda`:

```
app_f.input :user, :label_method => lambda{|u| "#{u.email} | #{u.firstname} #{u.lastname}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding this method to models/user.rb

```
# format label for formtastic dropdown menu
def to_label 
  "#{email} | #{firstname} #{lastname}" 
end
```

And I use it like this :

```
app_f.input :user, :include_blank => false, :label_method => :to_label
```